# gRPC Push and Fan-Out

Tags: .net, grpc

Is it possible and if so good practice to use gRPC as a push service with fan-out functionality?
In the examples given from Google, there is following code for the server side (C#):

```
    public override async Task ListFeatures(Rectangle request, IServerStreamWriter<Feature> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var responses = features.FindAll( (feature) => feature.Exists() && request.Contains(feature.Location) );
        foreach (var response in responses)
        {
            await responseStream.WriteAsync(response);
        }
    }
```

The problem is here that:

1. Data is only generated and written if the client explicitly asks for it.
2. Only the client that asked will get the new data.

I think what I need is:

1. Keep all the IServerStreamWriters for each client asked (subscribed).
2. Trigger the write by an external event when new data is available.
3. Write to all streamWriters

**Edit:**
Based on Carl's suggestions I now have the following:

Proto:

```
service PubSub {
 rpc Subscribe(Subscription) returns (stream Event) {}
 rpc Unsubscribe(Subscription) returns (Unsubscription) {}
}

message Event
{
   string Value = 1;
}
message Subscription
{
  string Id = 1;
}
message Unsubscription
{
  string Id = 1;
}
```

PubSubImpl:

```
public class PubSubImpl : PubSub.PubSubBase
{
    private readonly BufferBlock<Event> _buffer = new BufferBlock<Event>();

    private Dictionary<string, IServerStreamWriter<Event>> _subscriberWritersMap =
        new Dictionary<string, IServerStreamWriter<Event>>();

     public override async Task Subscribe(Subscription subscription, IServerStreamWriter<Event> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        //Dict to hold a streamWriter for each subscriber.
        _subscriberWritersMap[subscription.Id] = responseStream;

        while (_subscriberWritersMap.ContainsKey(subscription.Id))
        {
            //Wait on BufferBlock from MS Dataflow package.
            var @event = await _buffer.ReceiveAsync();
            foreach (var serverStreamWriter in _subscriberWritersMap.Values)
            {
                await serverStreamWriter.WriteAsync(@event);
            }
        }
    }

    public override Task<Unsubscription> Unsubscribe(Subscription request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        _subscriberWritersMap.Remove(request.Id);
        return Task.FromResult(new Unsubscription() { Id = request.Id });
    }

    public void Publish(string input)
    {
        _buffer.Post(new Event() { Value = input });
    }
}
```

"Push"s can now be sent like this:

```
   while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
    {
      pubsubImp.Publish(input);
    }
```

On client side I have:

```
public async Task Subscribe()
{
    _subscription = new Subscription() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
    using (var call = _pubSubClient.Subscribe(_subscription))
    {
        //Receive
        var responseReaderTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event received: " + call.ResponseStream.Current);
            }
        });

        await responseReaderTask;
    }
}

public void Unsubscribe()
{
    _pubSubClient.Unsubscribe(_subscription);
}
```

Client-Main works like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:50052", 
                                ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
    var subscriber = new Subsriber(new PubSub.PubSubClient(channel));

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await subscriber.Subscribe();
    }).GetAwaiter();

    Console.WriteLine("Hit key to unsubscribe");
    Console.ReadLine();

    subscriber.Unsubscribe();

    Console.WriteLine("Unsubscribed...");

    Console.WriteLine("Hit key to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

At the moment it looks like it works. Is that how it should/could be done?
Test solution can be found at:
https://github.com/KingKnecht/gRPC-PubSub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, though I can't comment on if it's good practice.  You need to keep track of each client as you said, and also make sure to remove clients as they disconnect to become unreachable.

Your general approach sounds right.  The push RPC should be bidirectional streaming (assuming each client can cause a push).   When the client connects to the server, record the client in a threadsafe collection.  When one of the clients sends a message, iterate through the collection sending the message to each of the connected clients.  If there are failures to send, remove the client from the client and close the connection.

There is a simpler version of this in the examples called "RouteGuide"   it implements a simple chat server in the languages that gRPC supports.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I had a closer look at the RouteGuide example. Unfortunately that didn't help me too much. I'm facing following problems: 1. stream gets closed if I leave the service method. Don't know how to avoid that. Endless-loop with sleep? 2. In all examples I've found the data to be streamed is triggered by a client. In my scenario only the server knows when new data is available and needs to be pushed.

Comment: If you look at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5253c8f9a899450397a5e46e4923d01ac9a66a27/examples/csharp/route_guide/RouteGuideServer/RouteGuideImpl.cs#L106  It avoids ever leaving the method too.  Instead of awaiting each write, you need to await on some queue that can be used to pass the messages between threads.

Comment: How could I have overlooked that:  "while (await requestStream.MoveNext()) " ... too late, too tired. Thx, for pointing me to this. Ok, problem of loop seems to be solved. Only one problem remains: How would the server push a message when new data is available? Act as an client and call that method?

Comment: It would still act as a server.  There are a couple different ways.  The simplest would be to start another thread that only does writing to the client, wait for the reading thread to notify it of new data.   Like I mentioned before, using some sort of thread safe queue would sit between the readers and writers.  This is just one way forward, and you can have others that might be higher performance or more idiomatic.  (They don't fit in the SO comments thought).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need to keep track of the clients in your server-app.  Instead, for each "push" method, create an `EventWaitHandle` and continuously wait on it.  Then in another context, signal the `EventWaitHandle` so that the waiting "push" method can `WriteAsync` to the client.

e.g.

```
public class PubSubImpl : PubSub.PubSubBase
{
    EventWaitHandle evwStatus = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
    string status;

    public override async Task Subscribe(Subscription subscription, IServerStreamWriter<Event> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        // respond with the current status
        await serverStreamWriter.WriteAsync(new Event { Value = status });
        // wait until we're signaled with a different status
        while(evwStatus.WaitOne())
        {
            await serverStreamWriter.WriteAsync(new Event { Value = status });
        }
    }   

    public void Publish(string input)
    {
        status = input;
        // let the waiting threads respond
        evwStatus.Set();
        // halt the waiting threads
        evwStatus.Reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: I never know about this thing before, it's pretty interesting do you know if it works well with Web environment such as long polling? single request and broadcast requests